# SNMP library for python failed return SNMP details

Tags: python, snmp, net-snmp, pysnmp, snmp-trap

Unable to get Fetch SNMP variable details using sample posted at (https://snmplabs.thola.io/pysnmp/quick-start.html) and got error response . please advice how to fix the error . Thanks in advance

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/WorkFiles/SNMPTest/SNMP.py", line 6, in <module>
    UdpTransportTarget(('snmpsim.try.thola.io', 161)),
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pysnmp\hlapi\transport.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.transportAddr = self._resolveAddr(transportAddr)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pysnmp\hlapi\asyncore\transport.py", line 63, in _resolveAddr
    '@'.join([str(x) for x in transportAddr]), sys.exc_info()[1]))
pysnmp.error.PySnmpError: Bad IPv4/UDP transport address snmpsim.try.thola.io@161: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failedcaused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

**

- Code used for testing

**

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
    getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
           CommunityData('public', mpModel=0),
           UdpTransportTarget(('snmpsim.try.thola.io', 161)),
           ContextData(),
           ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysDescr', 0)))
)

if errorIndication:
    print(errorIndication)
elif errorStatus:
    print('%s at %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                        errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1][0] or '?'))
else:
    for varBind in varBinds:
        print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))
```

Comment: snmpsim.try.thola.io does not resolve to anything

Comment: @RichardDodson sorry don't understand your comment "snmpsim.try.thola.io does not resolve to anything " . could you please provide more details . i am looking for solution how to test SNMP sample code with valid SNMP agent.

Comment: I mean that using DNS, snmpsim.try.thola.io does not resolve to anything.  That's why you're getting the error.

Comment: If you change `snmpsim.try.thola.io` to a an IP address or a hostname that's running SNMPv2 and configured with a community of `public`, it should work.

Comment: @RichardDodson Thanks for reply. I tried to get IPaddress for snmpsim.try.thola.io using ping cmd. but i did not get IP address from the domain. do you have any idea that is there any free SNMP responder domain to test SNMP ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know of any available SNMP servers.

Comment: Thanks . i have watched many youtube videos that they are using snmpsim.try.thola.io or demo.snmplabs.com and they able to get response. not sure why i am not getting

Comment: I think those videos must be old.  I have never heard of snmpsim.try.thola.io, but snmplabs.com is no longer owned by whoever managed pysnmp when it was active.

Comment: Thanks @RichardDodson. I managed find SNMP service in my organization and able get variables. want to check where we can watch SNMP trap logs in windows machine. Because when i run my SNMP trap script i am getting empty results. is it expected ?

Comment: SNMP TRAP operations are completely different from others (like GET/SET), so if you meet any issue there, then you should post a new question and share the contents of your TRAP command/operation.

Answer (score 0):

My company is trying to take over PySNMP ecosystem, as documented [here](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/issues/429).

So, you can use `demo.pysnmp.com` to test out typical SNMP commands/operations.